# Getting back original names from rpart.object

Tags: r, rpart

I have saved models which were created using the rpart package in R. I am trying to retrieve some information from these saved models; specifically from *rpart.object*. While the documentation - [rpart doc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf) - is helpful there are a few things it is not clear about:

1. How do I find out which variables are categorical and which are numeric? Currently, what I do is refer to the 'index' column in the *splits* matrix. I've noticed that for numeric variables only, the entry is not an integer. Is there a cleaner way to do this?
2. The *csplit* matrix refers to the various values a categorical variable can take using integers i.e. R maps the original names to integers. Is there a way to access this mapping? For ex. if my original variable, say, `Country` can take any of the values `France, Germany, Japan` etc, the csplit matrix lets me know that a certain split is based on `Country == 1, 2`. Here, rpart has replaced references to `France, Germany` with `1, 2` respectively. How do I get the original names - `France, Germany, Japan` - back from the model file? Also, how do I know what the mapping between the names and the integers is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is the `terms` component that would have that sort of information. `See ?rpart::rpart.object`.

```
fit <- rpart::rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit$terms  # notice that the attribute dataClasses has the information
attr(fit$terms, "dataClasses")
#------------
 Kyphosis       Age    Number     Start 
 "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

That example doesn't have a csplit node in its structure because none of hte variables are factors. You could make one fairly easily:

```
> fit <- rpart::rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + factor(findInterval(Number,c(0,4,6,Inf))) + Start, data = kyphosis)
> fit$csplit
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    3
[2,]    1    1    3
[3,]    3    1    3
[4,]    1    3    3
[5,]    3    1    3
[6,]    3    3    1
[7,]    3    1    3
[8,]    1    1    3
> attr(fit$terms, "dataClasses")
                                     Kyphosis 
                                     "factor" 
                                          Age 
                                    "numeric" 
factor(findInterval(Number, c(0, 4, 6, Inf))) 
                                     "factor" 
                                        Start 
                                    "numeric"
```

The integers are just the values of the factor variables so the "mapping" is just the same as it would be from `as.numeric()` to the `levels()` of a factor. If I were trying to construct a character matrix version of the `fit$csplit`-matrix that substituted the names of the levels in a factor variable, this would be one path to success:

```
> kyphosis$Numlev <- factor(findInterval(kyphosis$Number, c(0, 4, 6, Inf)), labels=c("low","med","high"))
> str(kyphosis)
'data.frame':   81 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Kyphosis: Factor w/ 2 levels "absent","present": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Age     : int  71 158 128 2 1 1 61 37 113 59 ...
 $ Number  : int  3 3 4 5 4 2 2 3 2 6 ...
 $ Start   : int  5 14 5 1 15 16 17 16 16 12 ...
 $ Numlev  : Factor w/ 3 levels "low","med","high": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 ...
> fit <- rpart::rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age +Numlev + Start, data = kyphosis)
> Levels <- fit$csplit
> Levels[] <- levels(kyphosis$Numlev)[Levels]
> Levels
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] "low"  "low"  "high"
[2,] "low"  "low"  "high"
[3,] "high" "low"  "high"
[4,] "low"  "high" "high"
[5,] "high" "low"  "high"
[6,] "high" "high" "low" 
[7,] "high" "low"  "high"
[8,] "low"  "low"  "high"
```

Response to comment: If you only have the model then use str() to look at it. I see an "ordered" leaf in the example I created that has the factor labels stored in an attribute named "xlevels":

```
$ ordered            : Named logi [1:3] FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Age" "Numlev" "Start"
 - attr(*, "xlevels")=List of 1
  ..$ Numlev: chr [1:3] "low" "med" "high"
 - attr(*, "ylevels")= chr [1:2] "absent" "present"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "rpart"
```

Comment: Thanks! - the term component does give me the variable types explicitly. Is there a way to access the name to integer mapping?

Comment: You will need to help understand what you mean by that phrase.

Comment: Adding details to the question.

Comment: Thanks again for your response!
To get back the level names you are using `kyphosis$Numlev`. But at this stage I only have access to the model file. I don't have the data.

Comment: If you call `fit <- rpart(..., model = TRUE)` then the `model.frame` of the training data is stored within the object (by default it is not). Then you can easily access it via `fit$model`. If it is not stored in the object but the data is still available in your R session, then you can use `library("partykit")` and `model.frame(fit)` which re-evaluates the `$call` using the model's `$terms`.

Comment: That nailed it! Thanks! `attr(fit, 'xlevels')` gives me what I need.

Comment: Thanks @AchimZeileis. Right now I have no control over how the model is saved; so I would have tomake the pessimistic assumption that data is not part of the model. Also I don't have access to the R session - I usually get these models sent to me offline :). But thanks for pointing me to `partykit` - I'm pretty sure I will be able to use it somewhere else.